# Python checking if code has errors

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have been assigned to write a program called author functions. One of the functions that I wrote appears to be right in my opinion, but I was wondering if there was any different way of writing the same thing, or if there is any errors in my function. The code is below. Thanks!

def clean_up(s):
    """ (str) -> str

```
Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

>>> clean_up('Happy Birthday!!!')
'happy birthday'
>>> clean_up("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
" it's on your left-hand side"
"""

punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
return result
```

####  Complete the following functions.

```
def avg_word_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
    text contains at least one word.

    Return the average length of all words in text. 

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul and Mary\n']
    >>> avg_word_length(text)
    5.142857142857143 
    """

    # To do: Fill in this function's body to meet its specification.

    x = ''
    for i in range(len(text)):
        x = x + clean_up(text[i])
        words = x.split()
    for word in words:
        average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
    return average
```

Comment: There seems to be something weird going on here: [There's another question containing a different version of this assignment.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704277/i-have-to-find-the-average-word-length).

Comment: Oh i apologize it the program starts with                                 def clean_up(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
    converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

    >>> clean_up('Happy Birthday!!!')
    'happy birthday'
    >>> clean_up("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
    " it's on your left-hand side"
    """
    
    punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
    result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
    return result

Comment: If you have additional context for the question, edit it into the question - it's incredibly hard to read code in comments.

Comment: That said, this question is far too open-ended for StackOverflow - you are not asking about a specific problem, but rather for someone to review your code and make suggestions. You might want to check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: your code is actually incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining the last and first words of each string together, you need to allow a space:

```
def avg_word_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
    text contains at least one word.

    Return the average length of all words in text.

    5.142857142857143
    """
    cleaned = " ".join([clean_up(w) for w in text]).split() # join using a space between to separate the start and end of the strings
    return sum(len(w) for w in cleaned) / len(cleaned)
```

In your code  `cooperpeter` becomes one word so your calculations are off.

`for word in words:` is doing nothing useful as `sum(len(word) for word in words)` is also looping over words and you should split when all the concatenation is complete, not every time through the loop:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    x += clean_up(text[i]) 
words = x.split() # outside the loop
```